# Add row to the bottom of table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a very simple VBA macro to add a new row to the bottom of the table. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub AddRow()
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows, Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(LR).Copy
    Rows(LR + 1).Insert
End Sub
```

When I try to run this, it says out of memory. What I am trying to achieve is a new row at the bottom of my existing table (with content in column A) that I will eventually use to total up the numbers above it, no matter how many columns there are above. What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub AddRow()
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(LR).Copy
    Rows(LR + 1).Insert
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You just had an error in the Range definition :

you used `"A" & Rows, Count` instead of `"A" & Rows.Count` (it a property of an object, so it's `Object.Property`

I would even suggest that you use a Worksheet variable for better referencing.

Here is your corrected code :

```
Sub AddRow()
    Dim LR As Long, _
        Ws As Workseet
    Set Ws = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("SheetName")
    LR = Ws.Range("A" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Ws.Rows(LR).Copy
    Ws.Rows(LR + 1).Insert
End Sub
```